# Validar información de un archivo excel luego de subido

Tags: php, phpexcel

alguien por aquí a realizado validación de la información de un archivo excel luego de subido con phpexcel, ya que busque ejemplos y no lo logro entender del todo si tuvieran un enlace con algún tutorial se lo agradecería bastante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno Encontré mi solución aquí lo aporto para quien lo necesite y si lo pueden mejorar bien :)

```
public function validatedata() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //Recuperar el archivo subido
        $file = $this->request->data('file');
        $nombre = $file["tmp_name"];
        //Instacia la clase de PhpExcel
        $objReader = new \PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
        //Cargo la Funcion para leer el Archivo
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
        $ObjPHPExcel = $objReader->load($nombre);
        //Habro la hoja 1 del archivo
        $ObjPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        //Convierto la data de la Hoja en un arreglo
        $dataExcel = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
        $cell = 7;
        //Me posiciono en la celda donde empiezen los datos
        $ObjHoja = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$cell)->getValue();
        //Una pequeña validacion si la hoja cuenta con datos
        if($ObjHoja != NULL){
            $group = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B3')->getOldCalculatedValue();
            //Cuento las filas para pasarlos al for
            $rows = count($dataExcel);
            //Arreglos para guardar los errores
            $persons = array();
            $errors = array();
            for($cell; $cell <= $rows ; $cell++){
                //Recupero las filas del excel
                $persons[$cell]['correo'] = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$cell)->getValue();
                $persons[$cell]['nombres'] = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$cell)->getValue();
                $persons[$cell]['ape_paterno'] = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$cell)->getValue();
                $persons[$cell]['ape_materno']= $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$cell)->getValue();
                $persons[$cell]['empresa'] = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$cell)->getValue();
                $persons[$cell]['nivel'] = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('F'.$cell)->getValue();
                $persons[$cell]['area'] = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G'.$cell)->getValue();
                //Valido si el arreglo en la posicion del correo esta vacio y guardo el error dentro de mi arreglo
                if($persons[$cell]['correo'] === NULL){
                   $errors[] = array('errors_mails' => "Error en la Fila ".$cell." Ingresar un correo valido");
                   //Valido con una funcion si el correo esta bien escrito o no
                }elseif (!$this->validatemail($persons[$cell]['correo'])) {
                    $errors[] = array('errors_mails' => "Error en la Fila ".$cell." El mail ".$persons[$cell]['correo']." es incorrecto");
                }

                if ($persons[$cell]['nombres'] === NULL) {
                    $errors[] = array('errors_names' => "Error en la Fila ".$cell." Ingresar un nombre valido");
                }elseif (!$this->validatext($persons[$cell]['nombres'])) {
                    $errors[] = array('errors_names' => "Error en la Fila ".$cell." nombre incorrecto ".$persons[$cell]['nombres']);
                }

                if ($persons[$cell]['ape_paterno'] === NULL) {
                    $errors[] = array('errors_lastnames' => "Error en la Fila ".$cell." Ingresar un apellido valido");
                }elseif (!$this->validatext($persons[$cell]['ape_paterno'])) {
                    $errors[] = array('errors_lastnames' => "Error en la Fila ".$cell." apellido incorrecto ".$persons[$cell]['ape_paterno']);
                }
                if (!$this->validatext($persons[$cell]['ape_materno']) && $persons[$cell]['ape_materno'] != NULL) {
                    $errors[] = array('errors_lastnames' => "Error en la Fila ".$cell." apellido materno incorrecto ".$persons[$cell]['ape_materno']);
                }
            }
            //Recupero La hoja 2 del Archivo y repito el proceso anterior sin realizar validaciones
            $Sheet_Area_Level = array();
            $ObjPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
            $datalevelarea = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
            for($row = 3;$row <= count($datalevelarea);$row++){
                $Sheet_Area_Level[$row]['area'] = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
                $Sheet_Area_Level[$row]['nivel'] = $ObjPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
            }
            $this->set('area_level',$Sheet_Area_Level);
            $this->set('group_persons',$group);
            $this->set('persons_excel',$persons);
            $this->set('errors_excel',$errors);
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error('El archivo se encuentra vacío');
        }
    }
}
```